# Normalization before PCA in NLP domains?

Tags: nlp, scikit-learn, clustering, pca

I'm working on a basic bag-of-words toy NLP pipeline for sentiment analysis using scikit-learn. From research of other questions here, it seems that the main applicable scaler for before PCA is the standardscaler. However, given that this is an NLP domain with many equivalent features, could the normalizer be considered instead?

For this dataset, I've tried the standardscaler before PCA, but I found that all categories were tightly clustered at 0, 0. If I replaced it with the normalizer, the data is much more spread out and some clusters start to form. Could this also be due to dataset size? I'm at about ~250 labeled documents. I'm only at the stage of looking for clusters.

My pipeline is CountVectorizer(n_gram=(1,1)) -> (either StandardScaler or Normalizer) -> PCA(n_components=2).

[image: standard scaled]

Above is the standard scaled version:

[image: normalized]

And here is the normalized version:

Comment: well, the normalized PCA does look better. I would try also tf-idf instead of bag of words, and maybe t-sne instead of PCA.

Comment: Yes I tried tf-idf as well. I did not get tight clumps but there werenty any groups starting to form. I did not do any scaling after tf-idf which is correct, right? I have not yet tried tsne.

Comment: I don't think you should normalize after tf-idf. If this does not give you nice clusters you can try: get more data, get richer features (richer than tf-idf) and try clustering algorithms and not just dimensionality reduction algorithms to see if the features seperates the classes to clusters.

Comment: Well, in the first figure, why don’t you remove the outlier and plot again. This way the plot would look much better and nicer.